# jQuery Mobile: refresh radio button selection periodically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button, refresh

I'm having trouble with refreshing a group of radio buttons, I hope someone could help.. The problem is how to display the newest selection(which radio is selected), so when one user select A, how could another user see radio button '#rA' is selected on his own device.

here is the markup: the div that displays the selected radio's value, and the 3 radio buttons.

```
<div id="radiostate"><?php echo $value;?></div>
<div id="test" >     
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="rB" value="B" data-theme="c" ><label for="rB">&nbsp;</label>  
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="rA" value="A" data-theme="a" ><label for="rA">&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="rC" value="C" data-theme="f" ><label for="rC">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

the code to refresh div "#radiostate" every 10 seconds, and get radio button checked based on $value:

```
 var refresh = setInterval(function(){
   $('#radiostate').load('getstate.php');
   var dbvalue = $('#radiostate').text();
   $('input[type="radio"][value="' + dbvalue +'"]').attr('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
 }, 10000);
```

this works fine to display the selected radio value (A, B, or C) in "#radiostate", but the radio buttons won't change... Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

**EDIT1**

I've also tried to put the radio buttons in another PHP(radio.php), and then load it every 10 seconds, but this totally messed up the style. 
If i don't include jquery.js and jquerymobile.js in radio.php, the radio buttons lose style:

[image: no jquery]

if I include jquery.js and jquerymobie.js, the index.php would looks like this, and the layer increases after each loading of radio.php:

[image: include jquery]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .attr to check the radio button use .prop

```
var refresh = setInterval(function(){
$('#radiostate').load('getstate.php');
var dbvalue = $('#radiostate').text();
$('input[type="radio"][value="' + dbvalue +'"]').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
}, 10000);
```